# Accumulate selections by expression using a for loop (Pyqgis)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, select-by-attribute, for-loop

I need to run a for loop to select features by their attributes, because the values are within lists (strkey and strvalue). I'm using the following script:

```
k=0
v=0
layer = iface.activeLayer()
for item in keys:
    listk = strkey[k]
    listv = strvalue[v]
    layer.selectByExpression('\"LINE_ID\" IN ('+listk+') AND \"Declividad\" IN ('+listv+')', QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)
    v=v+1
    k=k+1
```

The problem is that only the last feature is selected. Is like every loop the Qgis erases the old selection to select the new feature. 
Is there a way to accumulate the selections ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your selections are being overwritten on each iteration is because you passed `QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection` for the `SelectBehaviour` parameter. This sets a new selection each time, removing any existing selection.

Changing your `SelectBehaviour` argument to `QgsVectorLayer.AddToSelection` should do the trick.

Comment: simple like that! thanks! Do you have a good source so I could study more about this?